# CartoDB Visualization refresh in legends does not work until you switch template

Tags: carto

When changing the settings through the wizard, for example of the Bubble visuatlization, the legend does not update automatically.

I managed to update the legend by changing the template to 'custom' then back to 'bubble'

Is there another way to make it update?

Comment: Which properties are you trying to update? Can you explain us the steps to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got explanation from cartodb support:

There's a `lock` option that needed to be disabled in the legend config panel.